# Input data error using interpolate.splrep

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation, spline

I defined the two arrays:

```
x = array([ 0. , 50. , 55.5, 57.5, 55.5, 50. ,  0. ])
y = array([ 2.5,  2.5,  4.7, 10. , 15.3, 17.5, 17.5])
```

Then I interpolate with the command:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y)
```

This give me the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py", line 289, in splrep
res = _impl.splrep(x, y, w, xb, xe, k, task, s, t, full_output, per, quiet)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py", line 515, in splrep
raise _iermess[ier][1](_iermess[ier][0])
ValueError: Error on input data
```

Why are the input data not correct? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I'm not familiar with SciPy but I went to look at its documentation and in its description of function [`scipy.interpolate.splrep()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html#scipy-interpolate-splrep). There a sentence that says:

> The user is responsible for assuring that the values of x are unique. Otherwise, splrep will not return sensible results.

But you have many of the same values in your `x` array. Maybe that's why you have an error message?

Comment: Could be the problem, but in my data could be duplicated value. There is a manner to do a spline interpolation with these data?

Comment: Like I said I'm not familiar with SciPy. I answered your original question. I don't have an answer for your new question. Maybe you can look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) on SciPy website for answer?